# Vagrant synced_folder syntax for nfs options (trying to disable nfs_export)

Tags: nfs, vagrant

I'm trying to disable the nfs_export option in my Vagrantfile, so that Vagrant will not touch my `/etc/exports`.

The Vagrant documentation says:

> NFS synced folders have a set of options that can be specified that are unique to NFS. These are listed below. These options can be specified in the final part of the config.vm.synced_folder definition, along with the type option.
>
> nfs_export (boolean) - If this is false, then Vagrant won't modify your /etc/exports automatically and assumes you've done so already.
>
> https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html

I have no experience with Ruby syntax, but I guessed the following would achieve what I want:

```
 config.vm.synced_folder "/data", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", nfs_export: false
```

This does not work, however. Vagrant still keeps editing my exports file. What is the correct syntax?

I'm running the latest Vagrant 1.6.3 on OSX.

(The main reason I want to disable it, is that for some reason nfsd on my OSX machine does not come up again reliably after a `sudo nsfd restart`, which is run by Vagrant after updating the exports file)

Comment: The `nfsd restart` problem magically went away for me. I still don't know what caused it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only seems to edit the file to insert placemarkers. I'd submit a ticket on Github and say that you'd like the behaviour changed, see what response you get.

EDIT: Was feeling generous - https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4148 :)

Comment: Thanks. :-) In the meantime, the `nfsd restart` problem magically went away..